# ¿Cómo llamo a una vista desde un botón?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Quiero llamar a una vista desde un boton y que la vista que se llama muestre por lo mientras un hola, espero y me puedan ayudar.

Vista

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.grupo>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nom_grupo)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.alumno.nom)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.alumno.a_paterno)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.alumno.a_materno)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.alumno.edad)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nom_grupo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.alumno.nom)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.alumno.a_paterno)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.alumno.a_materno)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.alumno.edad)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id_grupo }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id_grupo }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id_grupo })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>


@Html.ActionLink("BOTÓN","datos", "grupoController")

</body>
</html>
```

CONTROLLER (grupoController)

```
public class grupoController : Controller
{
    private exampleEntities1 db = new exampleEntities1();

    // GET: grupo
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var grupo = db.grupo.Include(g => g.alumno);
        return View(grupo.ToList());
    }

    // GET: datos
    public ActionResult datos()
    {

        //var datos = db.alumno.Include(a => a.grupo);
        //ViewBag.mensaje = "HOLA MUNDO";
        return PartialView();
    }

    // GET: grupo/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        grupo grupo = db.grupo.Find(id);
        if (grupo == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(grupo);
    }

    // GET: grupo/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.id_alumno = new SelectList(db.alumno, "id_alumno", "nom");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: grupo/Create
    // Para protegerse de ataques de publicación excesiva, habilite las propiedades específicas a las que desea enlazarse. Para obtener 
    // más información vea https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id_grupo,nom_grupo,id_alumno")] grupo grupo)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.grupo.Add(grupo);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.id_alumno = new SelectList(db.alumno, "id_alumno", "nom", grupo.id_alumno);
        return View(grupo);
    }

    // GET: grupo/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        grupo grupo = db.grupo.Find(id);
        if (grupo == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.id_alumno = new SelectList(db.alumno, "id_alumno", "nom", grupo.id_alumno);
        return View(grupo);
    }

    // POST: grupo/Edit/5
    // Para protegerse de ataques de publicación excesiva, habilite las propiedades específicas a las que desea enlazarse. Para obtener 
    // más información vea https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id_grupo,nom_grupo,id_alumno")] grupo grupo)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(grupo).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.id_alumno = new SelectList(db.alumno, "id_alumno", "nom", grupo.id_alumno);
        return View(grupo);
    }

    // GET: grupo/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        grupo grupo = db.grupo.Find(id);
        if (grupo == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(grupo);
    }

    // POST: grupo/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        grupo grupo = db.grupo.Find(id);
        db.grupo.Remove(grupo);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: percibo que estás iniciando en ASP.net MVC, hace un tiempo hice este workshop donde traté en lo posible de explicar a detalle, espero te sea de utilidad https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero, cambia tu controlador de la siguiente manera

```
// GET: datos
public ActionResult datos()
{
    //var datos = db.alumno.Include(a => a.grupo);
    //ViewBag.mensaje = "HOLA MUNDO";
    return View();
}
```

Asegura que tu vista `datos.cshtml`, se encuentre ubicada en la siguiente ruta

```
-> Raiz del proyecto 
    -> Views 
        -> grupo 
             -> datos.cshtml
```

Y `datos.cshtml` ya puede contener el HTML que desees, para lo que pides solo copia:

```
Hola!!
```

También asegúrate de cambiar tu `ActionLink` de la siguiente manera:

```
@Html.ActionLink("BOTÓN", "datos", "grupo")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me funciono

Comment: Solo que tengo otra duda

Comment: Me podrias ayudar?

Comment: @Javierfr, claro que te puedo ayudar. Pero seria mejor que lo pusieras como otra pregunta, para que quede disponible para todas las personas que tengan tu misma inquietud

Comment: Gracias deja la comento